# Is it possible to get the "schema" for a k8s Kind from the cluster itself?

Tags: kubernetes

We currently use a pretty ancient version of k8s, v1.13.12 (although I just heard we may be upgrading to 1.24 soon).  It is often very frustrating to be certain what this k8s version supports, as the official docs only go as old as 1.23.

Is there anything we can get directly from the controller that is like a "schema", so if we have the Kind value and the version, we can determine exactly what properties are at least supported, if not exactly providing the rules for usage of those properties?